# write incremental number inside a file with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, versioning

i'm trying to figure out a way to make grunt write an incremental number or a hash on a file.

i have a file named `config.yml` which contains this:

```
version: 0.0.0
```

every time i change some files that i can specify somewhere (say all the `.js` and `.css` files), grunt should increment that number in some way.

i've seen some cache busting plugin but it's not what i am looking for as i don't want to have something like `config.987234892374982.yml` or `config.yml?v=1.0.0` for example. i'm looking for a way to have grunt to find that number in that file, change it in a way that makes sense (incrementally ideally, or a random hash) and then save the file.

can you help in some way? thanks a lot!

Comment: please google before oyu ask questions like this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-version-bump

I would recommend not doing the version bump whenever you save a file

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously recommend against automatic version bumping for anything beyond the build number.

A version number is more than just an indication of how many times your product has been built. In essence, a version number is a semantic promise to your end user concerning compatibility with earlier releases. Node.js and npm and other systems using versioning are built around the core concept that X.Y.Z version numbers contain the following logic:

1. Software that doesn't have the same X version will have severely breaking changes that require those upgrading (or downgrading) to completely redesign the logic of how they use the software, and in some cases they even have to find alternatives because what they're doing right now doesn't work anymore.
2. Software within the same X version can relatively easily be swapped out without having to make sweeping changes to your own site or product.
3. Software within the same Y version can be swapped out without having to change any code, because it's supposed to be only bug fixes and security fixes. Only code that works around the things fixed needs to be changed.
4. Software within the same Z version has the exact same source, so if you have 2 copies of the same Z.Y.Z version, they can be used interchangeably.

This is the core contract that NPM and other package managers ask all their content providers to adhere to. In fact, it has already been shown that in some cases where content providers don't adhere to this versioning system, consumers of this content who assume semantic versioning apply have found their build to fail. Many consumers assume that if version 3.5.N works, that any version within the 3.5.X family will be interchangeable, and make use of that assumption by automatically building their code with the most recent version of the 3.5.X family.

Because of this, it's not a good idea to automatically bump versions beyond the build number. Bumping the patch version should only be done when you actually release a new version to the public, not after every build. Bumping the minor version should only be done when you have added new features to the product, but without the need for major changes to software that uses your product. Bumping the major version should only be done when you make drastic and destructive changes to your API, like moving and/or removing functions, function parameters, objects or attributes.